# How to make fields default to values assigned to a jsonb field?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE inbound ( -- broadcasts received from RTs
    id SERIAL primary key,
    ts TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    rt VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    region region NOT NULL,
    channel channel NOT NULL,
    payload jsonb,
    messageid, -- denormalised
    messagetype -- denormalised
);
```

The payload might be: `{"a":{"messageid":"ABC123"}}` or `{"b":{"messageid":"ABC123"}}`.

I'd like the `messageid` field to always contain the value of the payload's object's `messageid` field, regardless of whether it's an `a` or a `b`.

I'd like the `messagetype` to be a `enum` value of `a` or `b`, reflecting the content of the payload.

Is denormalising JSON data the right thing to do in Postgres, or would I be better off setting up some form of view on the data?

Comment: Why do you need the `payload` field? It can be built at query time.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't explain this well.  The payload will usually contain a *complex* JSON object, where there is just one top-level property and it contains a "messageid".  I want to pick a couple of useful bits of data out of the JSON to make queries simpler and faster.

Comment: Still if the data is structured do not keep the payload. Make it all fields with the proper data type. JSON is only useful in the DB if the data is not structured, I mean, if you don't know its structure in advance.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto I know the basic structure, but the structure needs to be flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Do not keep the payload. Save the fields in instead. Assuming this schema:

```
create type messagetype as enum('a','b');
create table inbound (
    messageid text,
    messagetype messagetype
)
```

When the payload is received:

```
with p (payload) as ( values
    ('{"a":{"messageid":"ABC123"}}'::jsonb),
    ('{"b":{"messageid":"ABC123"}}')
)
insert into inbound (messagetype, messageid)
select key::messagetype, value ->> 'messageid'
from p, jsonb_each(payload)
```

And at request time:

```
select jsonb_build_object(messagetype, jsonb_build_object('messageid', messageid))
from inbound
;
       jsonb_build_object       
--------------------------------
 {"a": {"messageid": "ABC123"}}
 {"b": {"messageid": "ABC123"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I rarly work with jsons on DB so it is not fine piece of code but it works.

```
select myjsonb#>concat('','{',jsonb_object_keys(myjsonb),'}','')::text[]
  from (values ('{"a":{"messageid":"ABC123"}}'::jsonb ), ('{"b":
        {"messageid":"ABC123"}}'::jsonb)) a (myjsonb).
```

And if all yours jsons as simple as these from example (only one pair key-value, and only 2 keys possible) then don't store them as jsons but as 2 fields key_a and key_b or key and value columns.

Comment: Sorry, this is the reverse if what I'm looking for.  I already *have* the payload, but want to store the `messageid` property of the single top-level object, and the property-name of the single top-level object as "normal" fields to make queries simpler and faster.